# Passing a Variable to SED Command

Tags: sed, csh

What is the syntax to pass a variable to sed command that updates the second column in a CSV file. The variable name is `$tag`
This is the command I have used but I don't know where to put the variable exactly.

```
   basename "$dec" | sed 's/.*/&,A/' >> home/kelsabry/Downloads/Tests/results.csv
```

where `$dec`is variable that returns to me a certain directory.

Output:

```
Downloads, A
Documents, A
etc.
```

My command to pass the variable into sed to update the second column was:

```
   basename "$dec" | sed 's/.*/&,'$tag'/' >> home/kelsabry/Downloads/Tests/results.csv
```

but it gave me this output:

```
Downloads, '$tag'
Documents, '$tag'
etc.
```

So, where should I write the variable `$tag` in `sed` command?

Comment: If your problem is about columns, then `awk` might be more appropriate than `sed`. Actually if your problem is about CSV, then [`python`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html) is worth considering.

Comment: You should provide an example command that you tried, along with the input to the command and a desired output.

Comment: I have edited my question. Unfortunately, I can't use Python.

Comment: @mouviciel, how can I pass the variable to `awk` to update the second column with a field separator?

Comment: Are you sure this is exactly what you typed, because this seems to work for me.

Comment: I'm with kvantour on this one -- the commands in your question couldn't possibly generate the output you say you're getting. There are definitely quoting problems here. Please copy and paste the ACTUAL text from your terminal, and consider following the [MCVE guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for improving the question. With your new updates, this may in fact be an answerable question at this point, but including REAL commands and output will improve both the question and the answers you get.

Comment: Hey @iamauser, you're the only hold-voter who can be tagged here. Given the changes, how about reopening?

Comment: @ghoti, these are the actual commands that I have typed. The variable `$tag` is not updated and it appears with only its name as I shown in the question. These were the real commands.

Comment: @KarimElsabry, that's very curious. In the output you included, do you have any idea what might be adding the space after the comma? That's not in your sed script, and from the last output you included it obviously isn't part of the `$tag` variable either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `sed` is neither aware of fields nor capable of accepting variables. For that, you'd use shell or awk or shell or some other language.
`sed` is a *S*tream *ED*itor and in your example is taking input from stdin, not a variable.

If you do want to embed shell variables inside a sed script, understand that you are basically creating your sed script on-the-fly, and it's important to make sure you do it safely.

For example, if there's the possibility that your `$tag` variable might contain something that will cause misinterpretation of the sed script (i.e. perhaps it came from user input),
you need protection. In POSIX shell, perhaps something like this:

```
if [ "$tag" != "${tag#*[!A-Z]}" ]; then
  printf 'ERROR: invalid tag\n' >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

or even:

```
case "$tag" in
  [A-Z]) : ;;
  *) printf 'ERROR: invalid tag\n' >&2; exit 1 ;;
esac
```

then

```
# Note the alternative to `basename`
echo "${dec##*/}" | sed 's/$/,'"$tag"'/' >> path/to/file.csv
```

Note that sed doesn't know anything about fields or CSV.  `sed` is simply being used to append a string on to the end of the line.

Of course, in csh (which perhaps shouldn't be used for scripted automation), you are missing the more useful parameter expansion tools, but you can still protect yourself in other ways:

```
if ( $%tag == 1 ) then
  switch ($tag)
    case [A-Z]:
      printf '%s,%s\n' `basename "$dec"` "$tag"
      breaksw
    default:
      printf 'ERROR: invalid tag\n'
      exit 1
      breaksw
  endsw
else
  printf 'ERROR: invalid tag\n'
  exit 1
endif
```

*(Note: this is untested. Mileage varies based on multiple conditions. May contain nuts.)*

The issue you listed in your question was a quoting problem.  You said: `sed 's/.*/&,'$tag'/' >`.
An alternative might be to use awk:

```
echo "${dec##*/}" | awk -v tag="$tag" '{print $0 OFS tag}' OFS=, >> path/to/file.csv
```

Awk is a more complete programming language, and supports named variables, unlike sed. The `-v` option allows you to pre-load an awk variable with the contents of a shell variable.

[CSH is considered harmful](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html) by some. I'd recommend doing this in a POSIX shell instead, if only to take advantage of the much larger pool of experts who can help with your scripting questions. :)

Comment: Thank you, ghoti. I have used `awk` instead of `sed` and it paid off. But in general, variables can't be passed to `sed` at any case, right?

Comment: @KarimElsabry - Right, `sed` doesn't use variables (unless you consider the "hold space" to be a variable), and so it has no mechanism to load external data into a nonexistent data type. Everything that goes in to sed is either read from a file or from stdin.